# Horizontally centered with margin and max-width

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm looking to make `section` elements which have a maximum width of `1000px` with a margin of `1rem` that persists when the user resizes below whatever width that is.

```
main {
    align-items: center;
    background: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

section {
    align-self: stretch;
    background: #fff;
    display: flex;
    margin: 1rem;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

Unfortunately from my attempts at tweaking this, there are three results:

- I have something that properly centers with a maximum width of `1000px` but the side margins don't persist, because I'm using `1rem auto`.
- I have something that centers but makes no attempt to size the element.
- I have something that has the correct width and the margin persists, but it is left-aligned.

I'm not sure how to get this to work aside from using `@media` blocks, which isn't reliable since I'm using `rem` units for margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `width: calc(100% - 2rem);`

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2n571or2/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
main {
    align-items: center;
    background: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

section {
    background: #f00;
    display: flex;
    margin: 1rem;
    width: calc(100% - 2rem);
    max-width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    Section
  </section>
</main>
```